# How to resolve the conflict of keyboard shortcuts and customize all shortcuts?

Tags: customization, keyboard

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> is set for "other script" in previous versions, while now I am using 10.0 and find that this shortcut is also set for "Parallel Kernel Status", and actually the later is preferred.

I tried to solve the conflict problem by modifying the file `KeyEventTranslations`, but I could not find where to set "Parallel Kernel Status".

Does anyone knows how?

Answer (score 1):

"Parallel Kernel Status" is set in the following line of **MenuSetup.tr**

> ```
> MenuItem["Parallel &Kernel Status...", KernelExecute[Parallel`Palette`menuStatus[]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
> ```

On should not change these files, however you could change that line to

```
MenuItem["Parallel &Kernel Status...", KernelExecute[Parallel`Palette`menuStatus[]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, MenuKey["F5", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

in order to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> as the shortcut to open the "Parallel Kernel Status" palette.

You could also use `MenuKey["5", Modifiers->{"Control"}]`, but then you should also change `MenuItem["&Opposite Position", "Otherscript", MenuKey["5", Modifiers->{"Control"}]]` in **MenuSetup.tr** and
`Item[KeyEvent["5", Modifiers -> {Control}, CellClass -> BoxFormData], "Otherscript"]` in **KeyEventTranslations.tr** to something else.